# Running Tomcat Server with an artifact created by Maven into IntelliJ 13

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-13

It it is possible generate an artifact with maven before a Tomcat Server Run/Debug Configuration of IntelliJ 13?

I have tried to do something like this, using Maven profiles, in order to build the system for Development, Preview and Production environments.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To build a artifact with a profile you have to create a Maven Run/Debug configuration as in the following image

[image: Maven Build]

Then In Tomcat Run/Debug Configuration add above build in 'Before Launch' section by clicking the '+' button and select 'Run Another Configuration' then select the maven build.

[image: Do Another Tool]

The Result should like the below image.

[image: Result]

Now if you run Tomcat configuration first the maven build will be executed before Tomcat.

Comment: thanks for the steps, but I actually had to use one more step where in tomcat run configuration I had to go to the deployment tab and select the .war file generated from the maven build

Comment: Your answer was instrumental to solving my problem on the same subject matter. However, there are a couple of things that have changed in IntelliJ currently, try to find time to update it. Thanks.

Comment: what does the "dev" mean?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam , would you please simply explain how it works and if I am a very new beginner , do I need this param?

Comment: @Jaskey In maven pom.xml you can define profiles http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html. each profile can have its own dependencies, plugins and so on.. when you  run a maven command using a profile those dependencies will be included, plugins will be executed and so on.